# why does this code not set document title dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to dynamically update the document title from php script in regular intervals, it seems to not be working. I am a beginner to jquery, please help.

```
 <div id="code" style="border: 1px solid; "></div>
    <script>
     var blink = true;

    setInterval(function(){

    if(blink){
    jQuery('#code').load('test.php', function(result) {
    var theTitle = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];   
         theTitle= 'google'+jQuery('#code').html();

    });

        //theTitle.text =document.getElementById('code').value;
        blink = false;
    }else{

     jQuery('#code').load('test.php', function(result) {
    var theTitle = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];   
         theTitle= 'yahoo'+jQuery('#code').html();

    });

        blink = true;
    }
    }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
theTitle.textContent ="what you want"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
document.title = "new page title."
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery try this:

```
var blink = true;
setInterval(function(){
    $('#code').load('test.php', function(result) {
         $('title').text(blink ? 'google'+$('#code').html() : 'yahoo'+$('#code').html());
         blink = !blink;
    });
}, 2000);
```